# 'specified bucket does not exist ' error - S3 bucket with Policy disallow upload from particular IP

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cloudformation

I'm attempting to create an S3 bucket with a policy that disallows uploading anything from a particular public IP. It's written in YAML. Below is the code. Unfortunately I get this error:

The specified bucket does not exist. The bucket name sections match. Any idea what I am missing?

```
Resources:

  TestS3Bucket:
    Type: AWS::S3::Bucket
    Properties:
      BucketName: test4.test.bucket

  TestS3BucketPolicy:
    Type: AWS::S3::BucketPolicy
    Properties:
      Bucket: TestS3Bucket
      PolicyDocument:
        Version: 2012-10-17
        Statement: 
          Sid: SingleIPAllow
          Effect: Deny
          Principal: "*"
          Action: s3:PutObject
          Resource: arn:aws:s3:::test4.test.bucket
          Condition: 
            NotIpAddress: 
              aws:SourceIp: "***.***.***.***"
```

Comment: The documentation for `AWS::S3::BucketPolicy` says that `BucketName` should be the name of the S3 bucket. Try `Bucket: !Ref TestS3Bucket `.

Comment: Adding !Ref worked! The IP listed is my public IP address, any idea why it's allowing me to upload to this bucket?

Comment: You're denying putObject if the source IP is *not* yours. That said, it's unusual to deny access to a specific IP (it's much more common to deny access if not a specific IP or CIDR). Are you sure you want to deny access to one, and only one, IP?

Comment: I'm teaching myself CloudFormation and am looking for scenarios to code for and easily test. Blocking my own IP seemed like an easy thing to test. Does my own IP need to end with a / or /0?

Comment: I see. In CIDR notation, /32 represents a single IP address.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The BucketPolicy resource needs to point to a reference of the bucket. If you change your CloudFormation template to the following, it should work. Note the attribute `Bucket: !Ref TestS3Bucket` in the TestS3BucketPolicies Properties.

```
Resources:
  TestS3Bucket:
    Type: AWS::S3::Bucket
    Properties:
      BucketName: test4.test.bucket

  TestS3BucketPolicy:
    Type: AWS::S3::BucketPolicy
    Properties:
      Bucket: !Ref TestS3Bucket   // You need the !Ref here
      PolicyDocument:
        Version: 2012-10-17
        Statement: 
          Sid: SingleIPAllow
          Effect: Deny
          Principal: "*"
          Action: s3:PutObject
          Resource: arn:aws:s3:::test4.test.bucket
          Condition: 
            NotIpAddress: 
              aws:SourceIp: "***.***.***.***"
```

Comment: Adding !Ref worked! The IP listed is my public IP address, any idea why it's still allowing me to upload to this bucket?

Comment: Because with the current policy you are denying PutObject to all IP addresses except yours.

Comment: That makes sense, the Effect: Deny should be changed to a Effect: Allow

Comment: Yes. However, from a security perspective, I would never allow unauthenticated write access to everyone (except your IP). Having that said, please accept my answer if it solves your issue.